# Сокрытие элемента по клику

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Как сделать, чтобы после очередного клика по элементу то, что после первого появлялось, скрылось?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").click(function () {
        $("#gor").fadeIn([200],"slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: И в чём сложность? Показывайте, что не получается и мы поможем, а писать с нуля, да и ещё к такому ужасно оформленному вопросу - навряд ли кто станет!

Comment: я незная js и jquery

Comment: Так это не портал помощи утопающим, не умеете - учитесь, что не получается - поможем. Решать Ваши задачи за Вас никто не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая хорошая функция в jQuery: toggle(). Вот как будет работать:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").toggle(function () {
        $("#gor").fadeIn([200],"slow");//1й клик
    }, funciont(){
        $("#gor").fadeIn([600],"slow");//2й клик
    });
});
```

Comment: 2й клик - необходимое действие сами напишете, я просто скопипастил что бы показать суть.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще использовать проверку

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").click(function () {
        var gor = $("#gor");
        if(gor.css('display')=='none'){gor.fadeIn([200],"slow");}
        else{gor.fadeOut([200],"slow"}
    });
});
```